# Netbeans - "Cannot run /usr/bin/firefox" when running web project

Tags: java, firefox, web, netbeans

I created a new web project on Netbeans. As usual, in order to be sure that everything is OK before coding, I tried to run my project directlywith Netbeans.

For what I can see, evrything is great, except that I have a popin with the followed message : "Cannot run /usr/bin/firefox". A fex months ago, running a project by this way was perfectly good. I don't know what has changed.

What I tired/checked :

- The file /usr/bin/firefox exists ;
- I give it all the rights (reading, writing, executing) ;
- if I specify another browser in Netbeans, the result is the same (of course, the message changes but keeps the same format) ;
- My firefox is pefectly running, excpet for that.

I'm currently on Debian and Firefox v45.9.0.

Do you have any idea of what could cause this problem ? Any help is welcome !

Marine

Answer (score 0):

Go to Netbeans menu Tools > Options. In the General Tab, Web browser section tab click edit.

Select Web browser as firefox (I guess it is already like that for you).
On the right hand side, if the text in Arguments section is **-remote "openURL({URL})"** , bingo that could be the problem.

Change it to **{URL}**.

Save and try running the project. Hope it works..